# prepros convert jade file into html file only

Tags: php, html, file, pug

I was on prepos 5 and since two days i'm on prepos 6.

I work with pug (jade) and I  convert jade files (.jade) with prepros.
But I want to convert jade file (.jade) into php file (.php) and not into html file (.html).

I know how to do this with prepos 5 but I want to work with the latest version, and my prepos 5 doesn't work anymore so ...

I tried into prepos (v6) settings/ compiler settings/ pug(jade) but nothing to do what I want.
Of course I have tried all the settings but my english isn't perfect and maybe it was under my eyes.

If someone know where is this setting or if it's not possible yet.

Thank's for your time ;) !

Answer (score 0):

You need open the `prepros-6.config` file and change index.html to index.php.